# How can I use ng-model with ng-hide?

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field that uses ng-model, when the length of the input is greater than 3 characters I would like to use ng-hide to hide an element. How should I approach this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use ng-if instead so it would remove it from the DOM rather than just adding "display: none" to where ever you're using ng-hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Ng-Hide**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="letter" ng-hide="letter.length > 3"/>
</div>
```

Basically what i am doing above is setting the ng-model then im making an expression inside the text. The expression states that if the length of the model letter (A.K.A input text) has a length greater than 3 you hide it. Here is the offical documentation of ng-hide:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

The syntax for ng-hide goes like this:

```
<element ng-hide="expression"></element>
```

So if the expression comes to become true then it hides if not it shows. And talking about showing you can also do the opposite with the ng-show directive

### Ng-Show

```
<element ng-show="expression"></element>
```

In this case if the expression is true it will show otherwise it would hide. Here is the offical documentation for ng-show:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Thanks for the response. This approach works when trying to hide the input field itself, but not when trying to hide an element outside of this <div>. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your code @chuck280 so i can figure it out?

Comment: Wow your response is confusing every time i read it @chuck280 you want to hide the elements outside the div? So the Body??

Comment: <div ng-hide ="letter.length > 3">
<p> hello</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="letter"/>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

```
<element-to-hide ng-hide="inputModelHere.length > 3" />
```